How to render text using FreeType and OpenGL
Currently I managed to render quads which look like their corresponding characters if I'm not multiplying by sampled, but whenever I do so then the quads turn fully transparent and disappear
Setup for FreeType and FontConfig
c.glEnable(c.GL_BLEND);
c.glBlendFunc(c.GL_SRC_ALPHA, c.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

var ft: c.FT_Library = undefined;
_ = c.FT_Init_FreeType(&ft);
var face: c.FT_Face = undefined;

const font_path = getFontPath(alloc, font.family) catch unreachable; // Returned path matches font
_ = c.FT_New_Face(ft, font_path.ptr, 0, &face);
_ = c.FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 16);
c.glPixelStorei(c.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

for (keys_s.search) |key| {
    keys_s.char_info.put(key, Character.new(face, key)) catch unreachable;
}

Struct holding info about Character
pub const Character = struct {
texture_id: u32,
size: [2]i32,
bearing: [2]i32,
advance: [2]u32,

fn new(face: c.FT_Face, key: u8) Character {
    var texture: u32 = undefined;
    c.glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    c.glBindTexture(c.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    c.glTexImage2D(
        c.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        c.GL_RED,
        @intCast(face.*.glyph.*.bitmap.width),
        @intCast(face.*.glyph.*.bitmap.rows),
        0,
        c.GL_RED,
        c.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        face.*.glyph.*.bitmap.buffer,
    );

    c.glTexParameteri(c.GL_TEXTURE_2D, c.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, c.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    c.glTexParameteri(c.GL_TEXTURE_2D, c.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, c.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    c.glTexParameteri(c.GL_TEXTURE_2D, c.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, c.GL_LINEAR);
    c.glTexParameteri(c.GL_TEXTURE_2D, c.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, c.GL_LINEAR);

    return .{
        .texture_id = texture,
        .size = .{
            @intCast(face.*.glyph.*.bitmap.width),
            @intCast(face.*.glyph.*.bitmap.rows),
        },
        .bearing = .{
            @intCast(face.*.glyph.*.bitmap_left),
            @intCast(face.*.glyph.*.bitmap_top),
        },
        .advance = .{
            @intCast(face.*.glyph.*.advance.x >> 6),
            @intCast(face.*.glyph.*.advance.y >> 6),
        },
    };
}
};

Actual function that renders text (setColor just sets uniforms to chosen color)
pub fn renderText(self: *const Self, text: []const u8, x: i32, y: i32) void {
    setColor(self.config.font.color, self.egl.text_shader_program.*);
    c.glActiveTexture(c.GL_TEXTURE0);

    for (text, 0..) |char, i| {
        const ch = self.config.keys.char_info.get(char).?;
        const move: i32 = @intCast(ch.advance[0] * i);

        const x_pos = x + ch.size[0] + move;
        const y_pos = y - ch.bearing[1];

        const vertices = [_]i32{
            x_pos,              y_pos,              0, 1,
            x_pos + ch.size[0], y_pos,              1, 1,
            x_pos,              y_pos + ch.size[1], 0, 0,
            x_pos + ch.size[0], y_pos + ch.size[1], 1, 0,
        };


        c.glBindTexture(c.GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.texture_id);
        c.glBindBuffer(c.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.egl.VBO);
        c.glBufferSubData(c.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, @sizeOf(i32) * vertices.len, &vertices);
        c.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, c.GL_INT, c.GL_FALSE, 0, null);
        c.glDrawElements(c.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, c.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, null);
    }
}

I also use this EBO to render the quads
const indices = [_]i32{
    0, 1, 3,
    0, 2, 3,
};

c.glBindBuffer(c.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO[0]);
c.glBufferData(c.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, @sizeOf(i32) * indices.len, &indices, c.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

Fragment shader
#version 460 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

uniform vec4 u_color;
uniform sampler2D text;

in vec2 v_texcoords;

void main() {
  vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(text, v_texcoords).r);
  FragColor = u_color * sampled;
}

Vertex shader
#version 460 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertex;

uniform mat4 projection;

out vec2 v_pos;
out vec2 v_texcoords;

void main() {
  gl_Position = projection * vec4(in_pos.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
  v_texcoords = vertex.zw;
}


What is the question here?

@sigod the question is, why cant I render the text, thought it was obvious but I edited the title now

It looks like you're not telling the FreeType library to load/render any glyphs. Try calling the FT_Load_Char function before this line in the loop:
keys_s.char_info.put(key, Character.new(face, key)) catch unreachable;

Also, avoid using catch unreachable; it's only intended for situations where you can guarantee that the code will never fail. Just use try.

if (c.FT_Load_Char(face, key, c.FT_LOAD_RENDER) == 1) {     std.log.err("Failed to load glyph for character {s}\n", .{[_]u8{key}});     std.process.exit(1); }
sorry, I accidentally took that part out of question when trying to simplify it. I currently have it at the beggining of Character.new().

Then I'm not sure what the problem is. (It's strange that you use u8 for a character, I'd use at least u21 (because of UTF-8), but it should still work at least partially). Anyway, being able to debug an issue like this yourself is an important skill to practice.

I'll try to figure something out then, one last question though, when printing texture id, each of the characters returns the same id 2863311530, is it expected?

I've never tried printing texture ids, but it doesn't sound right. Each texture should have a unique id.

I managed to render textures to the quads, turns out I was trying to bind textures before initializing any context.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Community I won't
